# Why does `print "XYZ$_"` work but `print "$_XYZ"` doesn't?

Tags: perl

For input `abc`, the code

```
perl -ne 'print "XYZ$_"'
```

prints `XYZabc`, but after switching the order of `$_` and `XYZ`, i.e.

```
perl -ne 'print "$_XYZ"'
```

it prints nothing. Why?

Comment: `use strict;` would have given you a useful error message here, instead of just "giving nothing"

Comment: Presumably, you don't have a variable called `$_XYZ` :-)

Answer (score 6):

`XYZ` can be part of a variable name, so `$_XYZ` is a variable name, rather than `$_` followed by a literal `XYZ`.

You can split the string up:

```
perl -ne 'print $_ . "XYZ"'
```

Comment: or `print $_, "XYZ"` or `printf "%sXYZ", $_` etc.

Comment: what I'm trying to achieve is to add some characters at the every line of the text file.  

The code `perl -ne 'print "XYZ$_"' $newfilename.txt > $newfilename-XYZ.txt'` works perfectly to add at the begining, but the above solutions to add at the end do not work

Comment: @KoahNuttler — You were asking about the Perl. Even though it is a similar problem, Bash is a different programming language.

Comment: @Quentin you suprised me a lot, though I'm a novice I thought that using perl inside bash shouldn't make any difference. Sorry for the confusion then, thank you for all the answers, but are you able provide me with any solution for bash/perl combination?

Comment: @KoahNuttler — The Perl bit (`print "XYZ$_"`) is covered by this answer, and the change I suggested works fine (at least as far as putting the variable before the hard coded bit is concerned, you might want to do some additional work to deal with putting the new line in a different place) in that context. If you want to mess around with the variable order in the bash portion (`$newfilename.txt > $newfilename-XYZ.txt`) then you should ask a new question about it.

Comment: @KoahNuttler You probably want the `-l` option, as in `perl -nle`. Otherwise your newlines are going to be messed up.

Comment: @melpomene thank you for the solution, it adds the characters but not at the end of the existing line, but in a new lines.

Comment: @KoahNuttler Alternative: prepend `perl -pe 's/^/XYZ/'` append `perl -pe 's/$/XYZ/'`

Answer (score 4):

Perl identifiers may contain any letters, digits, or underscore, so you are asking perl to print the value of the variable `$_XYZ`, which doesn't exist

You may surround the name of the variable with braces `{ ... }` to separate it from any surrounding characters, like so

```
perl -ne 'print "${_}XYZ"'
```